# Remove duplicate objects from array based on one value, keep lowest of other value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Right now I have an array of objects in PHP, and some of them have a duplicate value for "id". I'm  trying to remove the duplicates but I want to keep the one with the lowest value for "qty".

I know how you'd normally remove duplicate whole objects from an array, but not only if one value is a duplicate and how to keep the lower of another value.

Example:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        qty: 200
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        qty: 190
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        qty: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        qty: 12
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        qty: 10
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        qty: 5
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        qty: 5
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        qty: 2
    },
]
```

What I want to end up with would be..

```
[
    {
        id: 4,
        qty: 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        qty: 5
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        qty: 10
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        qty: 190
    }
]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks almost like JSON, so assuming you `$array = json_decode($json, true)` to an associative array:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'qty'), SORT_DESC, $array);
$result = array_column($array, null, 'id');
```

- Extract an array of `qty` and sort that descending, sorting the original by that
- Extract from that an array with `id` as the key

Extracting with `array_column()` will cause the last `id` key to overwrite the previous ones.  The last one will be the one with the lowest `qty` since it was sorted DESCending.

If you need to get it back to a JSON object, then just re-index:

```
$json = json_encode(array_values($result));
```

Comment: Very nice. This did pretty much exactly what I was aiming for. Picking through the documentation for all those functions now.

If I wanted to sort this again at the end so the array is in the order of highest to lowest id, what would that be? I just tried `array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC);` as well as `SORT_DESC` but am still getting them in 1, 2, 3, 4 order but want 4, 3, 2, 1 order.

Comment: Do you mean highest to lowest `id`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yup. I just tried every sort method I could think of on it and I'm still getting them from lowest to highest `id` for some reason.

Comment: If so then just sort by key in reverse: `krsort($result);` since the keys are now the `id`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's still giving me an object with 4 objects in it sorted 1, 2, 3, 4 for some reason.

Comment: In your example there are only 2 unique ids so I don't know where 3,4 are coming from: https://3v4l.org/YtPkr

Comment: @AbraCadaver sorry, it was just an example. In actual use I could have 50+ id's. I guess in this example what I'm saying is I'd want the final output to be 2, 1. I should have done that in the question but I didn't think I'd run into issues sorting at the end lol

Comment: Works fine, not sure how you are doing it. See here: https://3v4l.org/2Q3Oe

Comment: Not sure why. Maybe it's something Laravel was doing when sending it. I ended up getting it in the desired order by doing `$result = array_values($result);` which makes absolutely no sense to me.. but hey it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AbraCadaver came up with such a good answer, but I worked hard to come up with mine, so I want to share it in case it is useful for someone. If anything, it may provide useful for an expanded or more complex array. I went the route of creating a nested loop. Here is the code:

```
    $newArray = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++)
    {
        $id_column = array_column($newArray, 'id');
        $qty_column = array_column($newArray, 'qty');
        if (!in_array($myArray[$i]['id'],$id_column)) {
            array_push($newArray, $myArray[$i]);
        }
        else {
            $id_pos = array_search($myArray[$i]['id'],$id_column);
            if ($myArray[$i]['qty'] < $qty_column[$id_pos])
            {
                array_splice($newArray,$id_pos,1,$myArray[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically I create a new empty array. I loop through each element of the original array to see if it's in the new array. If not, I add it, and if it is already in the new array, then I check the new Array to see if the qty for that id is higher, if so, I splice in the current row.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to involve a sorting algorithm -- that would only negatively impact the script performance.

If a row's id is not yet presented in the output array, push it into the output array with a temporary first level key.  If the row's id is already in the output array, but has a lesser qty, then overwrite the row in the output array.

This task never needs more than one loop.  If you want to remove the temporary first level keys, then call `array_values()` after looping.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DES4t))

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'qty' => 200],
    ['id' => 1, 'qty' => 190],
    ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 10],
    ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 12],
    ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 10],
    ['id' => 3, 'qty' => 5],
    ['id' => 4, 'qty' => 5],
    ['id' => 4, 'qty' => 2],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['id']]) || $row['qty'] < $result[$row['id']]['qty']) {
        $result[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'qty' => 190,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'qty' => 10,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'qty' => 5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'qty' => 2,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible answers, assuming **$your_input** contains your data as a string…

### Method 1

```
<?php
$your_input=preg_replace('#\s*\{\s*id\s*:\s*([^,]+?),\s*qty\s*:\s*([^,\}]+?)\s*\}\s*(,)?#','{"id":"$1","qty":"$2"}$3',$your_input);
$your_input=json_decode($your_input,true);
$result=[];
foreach($your_input as $a) 
if (!array_key_exists($a['id'],$result) or $a['qty']<$result[$a['id']]['qty'])
{
$result[$a['id']]['id']=$a['id'];
$result[$a['id']]['qty']=$a['qty'];
}
$result=json_encode(array_values($result),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

### Method 2

```
<?php
$your_input=str_replace(['        ',':'],['"','":'],$your_input);
$your_input=json_decode($your_input,true);
usort($your_input,function($a,$b){return $a['qty']==$b['qty']?0:($a['qty']>$b['qty']?-1:1);});
foreach($your_input as $b) $result[$b['id']]=['id'=>$b['id'],'qty'=>$b['qty']];
$result=json_encode(array_values($result),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

After Method 1 or Method 2 the **$result** variable should contains the following data string…

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "qty": 190
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "qty": 10
    }
]
```