# Filter rows with unique column value and prioritize rows with a particular value in another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering

I have an array that needs to be unique and I need to have a condition to check if value `dis` is in ANSWERED status. If yes then keep it and remove the row that is in NO ANSWER status.

this is my full array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 960
            [dis] => ANSWERED
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 596
            [dis] => NO ANSWER
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 596
            [dis] => ANSWERED
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 595
            [dis] => NO ANSWER
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 595
            [dis] => NO ANSWER
        )

)
```

after removing duplicates:

```
Array
(
    [dest] => 960
    [dis] => ANSWERED
)
Array
(
    [dest] => 596
    [dis] => NO ANSWER
)
Array
(
    [dest] => 596
    [dis] => ANSWERED
)
Array
(
    [dest] => 595
    [dis] => NO ANSWER
)

with this code :
foreach(array_unique($testArr, SORT_REGULAR) as $doc)
{
    print_r($doc);
}
```

What I need to do now is remove array[1] that is NO ANSWER because array[2] with key : dis is ANSWERED

Comment: Generally a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42281756/2943403 which asks for a technique to remove duplicates and favor lesser values in the secondary column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps :

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['dest' => 960, 'dis' => 'ANSWERED'],
    ['dest' => 596, 'dis' => 'NO ANSWER'],
    ['dest' => 596, 'dis' => 'ANSWERED'],
    ['dest' => 595, 'dis' => 'NO ANSWER'],
    ['dest' => 595, 'dis' => 'NO ANSWER'],
];

// Step 1: Filtering step
$intermediate = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!isset($intermediate[$item['dest']])) {
        $intermediate[$item['dest']] = $item['dis'];
    } elseif ($item['dis'] === 'ANSWERED') {
        $intermediate[$item['dest']] = $item['dis'];
    }
}

// Step 2: Rebuild to final format
$result = [];
foreach ($intermediate as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = ['dest' => $key, 'dis' => $value];
}

print_r($result);
```

Gives :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 960
            [dis] => ANSWERED
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 596
            [dis] => ANSWERED
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [dest] => 595
            [dis] => NO ANSWER
        )
)
```

Comment: Definitely can be done with one loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa with 0 loop and `array_reduce()` too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While iterating assign temporary keys while pushing rows into your result array. Also, if the dest is not yet represented in the result array or if the dis is ANSWERED, then store the row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9OVM0))

```
$result =[];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['dest']]) || $row['dis'] === 'ANSWERED') {
        $result[$row['dest']] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));  // reindex the result array
```

Comment: @Assaf if that answer is "perfect", then this answer is more "perfect".

Comment: Yeah that is also perfect :)

Comment: both solutions are good and he answered my question and solve it before your solution , thank you for your solution as well ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_map function

```
function fun2($v1)
{
    if ($v1->dis=='ANSWERED') return $v;
}
$finalArray = array_map("fun1", $testArr));
print_r($finalArray)
```

Comment: This unexplained snippet does not satisfy the question requirements.